# CSS: Truncate String with Ellipsis

Tags: css, reactjs, overflow, truncate, ellipsis

I'm working on a React.js project and this is a sample code of it.

```
<div
  style={{
    backgroundColor: '#ffff00',
    maxWidth: '100%'
  }}
>
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
  <span
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#00ff00',
      color: '#ffffff'
    }}
  >
    x
  </span>
</div>
```

This `div` contains in an another parent container. Because of the small size of that parent container, the text is not properly visible inside the child container and completely hide the `span`. [image]

So I refactor styles of the child `div` and I could fix the text issue with dots.

```
<div
  style={{
    backgroundColor: '#ffff00',
    maxWidth: '100%',
    display: 'inline-block',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
  }}
>
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
  <span
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#00ff00',
      color: '#ffffff'
    }}
  >
    x
  </span>
</div>
```

Result: [image]

But still, I couldn't see the `span`. How can I make that visible at the end of the child `div` container? I only want to truncate the text, not the `span`.

**I'm not allowed to do any changes in `span` (like style changes) or with element structure.**

Comment: Can the text ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 be wrapped in span?

Comment: Can't, I'm not allowed to do any structural changes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you.

```css
html {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  
}
#text {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p id="text">
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
  </p>
  <span>
    x
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and the result of this is what I really want, But I'm not allowed to do any structural changes. So I can't add the text (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789) into an another element.

Answer (score 1):

Only way I can think of without wrapping the text in a node:

Add CSS to the parent

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div
      class="wrapper"
      style="
        background-color: #ffff00;
        maxWidth: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        whiteSpace: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        textOverflow: ellipsis;
      "
    >
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
      <span
        style="
          background-color: #00ff00;
          color: #ffffff;
        "
      >
        x
      </span>
    </div>
```

Take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-night-1pwvh?file=/src/index.js